BMS HY2120 automatic initialization
I'm using the HYCON HY2120 for a project and I've followed the recommended schematic :

I have just added a switch to connect/disconnect the PB+ and VDD of the cells. I have tried the overcharge and discharge feature and it works well.
My problem is that I need to briefly short CS and VSS to start the IC at initialization. I've looked through the datasheet and I have found this (page 12) :

In my case, connecting the charger is not an option. So far I'm using a push button to briefly short VSS and CS but I would prefer some other components to do that automatically when I close my switch. I've seen some circuits that could work but always require a 5V or a 3V3 to bias the circuit correctly. The only signals I have are PB+, PB- and VSS. Currently when the circuit is open on my board PB- is -6V compared to GND but I don't think that it is a good idea to rely on this value.
I feel like I'm missing something since I'm probably not the first to encounter this issue with BMS.
